# How to open multiple apps in one go in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am a software programmer and I have to start many applications when I start my computer like `Visual Studio`, `SQL Server Management Studio`, `VSS` etc. Can I make a short cut (or something else) that start all applications in one go?

Comment: Put them into your startup folder? Write a batch file to start them all?

Comment: Windows 10 1709+ will automatically restart your applications in most applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can create a customize shortcut to launch multiple application.

To do it, follow these steps:

**Step 1:** Open the Start menu and go to All apps to find the first program you want to open in your batch. Right-click on the program and click Open file location.

**Step 2:** A File Explorer window will open to the program's location. Right-click on the program in the File Explorer window and click Properties.

**Step 3:** In the Properties window, click the Shortcut tab. Find Target: field, select the text in the textbox, and copy it. Open up a new Notepad noteand paste this text in that window.

**Step 4:** Repeat steps 1 through 3 for the second (and third, and fourth) program(s) you want to open in this shortcut.

**Step 5:** Once you have collected the target info for all of the programs you want to open in one shortcut, arrange the text so it looks like this:

[image]

**Step 6:** Save your file as a BAT file to the desktop. To do this, go to File > Save As, navigate to the desktop, and type the name of your shortcut followed by .bat (for example,mullan) in the File name field. In the Save as type field, click the dropdown menu and select All files. Then click Save.

---

Copy/pasteable example:

```
@echo off

cd "%windir%\system32\notepad.exe"
start notepad.exe

cd "%windir%\system32\mspaint.exe"
start mspaint.exe

cd "%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe"
start mstsc.exe

exit
```

Comment: For me, I have to put the name of the .exe file *without* quotes, like you have in your answer. When I put the file name into quotes, it starts a cmd shell in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.lnk | Foreach-Object { Invoke-Item $_.Name }
```

This will open all shortcuts (to programs or documents) in the current folder. You can save it as a ps1 script or compile it to an exe with the ps2exe project (https://github.com/MScholtes/PS2EXE).